# Graphics for bouncing ball in multi-threaded program in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to adapt a program I have created for bouncing a ball in Java. I am very new so apologies if the solution is obvious. I have used the following code to create an array of bouncing balls, and then subsequently create two threads with the balls bouncing.

I am trying to achieve this without the array. So, that each thread has only 1 ball.
I feel like the answer is staring me in the face but I just cannot solve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;



 public class AClass implements Runnable {  
     private JFrame mainFrame;
     private DrawPanel drawPanel;
    // private java.util.List<Ball> balls;


     private int windowWidth = 640;
     private int windowHeight = 480;
     private String windowLabel = "Multi-threaded ball application";

     public void run() {

         //balls = new ArrayList<>();
         //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         //System.out.print("Enter the number of balls you would like to create:");
         //int n = sc.nextInt();
         //sc.close();
    
    
         /* Generate balls */
         //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Ball ball = new Ball(
                     /* Random positions from 0 to windowWidth or windowHeight */
                     (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * windowWidth),
                     (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * windowHeight),
                     /* Random size from 10 to 30 */
                     (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10,
                     /* Random RGB colors*/
                     new Color(
                             (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                             (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                             (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256))
                     ),
                     /* Random velocities from -5 to 5 */
                     (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
                     (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5)
             );

            // balls.add(ball);
        // }

         /* Initialize program */
         mainFrame = new JFrame();
         drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
         mainFrame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
         mainFrame.setTitle(windowLabel);
         mainFrame.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
         mainFrame.setVisible(true);
         mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         while (true) {
             //for (Ball b: balls) {
                 ball.update();
            // }

             /* Give Swing 10 milliseconds to see the update! */
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(10);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             mainFrame.repaint();
         }
     }

    public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
         /**
          * 
          */
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         @Override
         public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
             super.paintComponent(graphics);

            // for (Ball b: balls) {
                 ball.draw(graphics);
            // }

         }
     }

     class Ball {//ball class
         private int posX, posY, size;
         private Color color;

         private int vx = 5;
         private int vy = 5;

         public Ball(int posX, int posY, int size, Color color, int vx, int vy) {
             this.posX = posX;
             this.posY = posY;
             this.size = size;
             this.color = color;
             this.vx = vx;
             this.vy = vy;
         }

         void update() {

             if (posX > mainFrame.getWidth() || posX < 0) {
                 vx *= -1;
             }

             if (posY > mainFrame.getHeight() || posY < 0) {
                 vy *= -1;
             }

             if (posX > mainFrame.getWidth()) {
                 posX = mainFrame.getWidth();
             }

             if (posX < 0) {
                 posX = 0;
             }

             if (posY > mainFrame.getHeight()) {
                 posY = mainFrame.getHeight();
             }

             if (posY < 0) {
                 posY = 0;
             }

             this.posX += vx;
             this.posY += vy;

         }

         void draw(Graphics g) {
             g.setColor(color);
             g.fillOval(posX, posY, size, size);
         }
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {  
         AClass ex = new AClass();  
         Thread t1= new Thread(ex);  
         Thread t2 = new Thread(ex);
         t1.start();  
         t2.start();
         //System.out.println("Hi");  
     }  
 }
```

Comment: Swing is not thread safe - you should be using a Swing Timer

Comment: I don't think your intention is the correct approach (trying to have each ball be it's own `Thread`), you're going to quickly end up with all sorts of issues trying to do collision detection, as the state of each ball is always changing independent of each other and it won't scale well.  The array and a Swing `Timer` would be a more suitable solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Swing is not thread safe.  You should not be updating the UI (or any state the UI relies on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

I don't think your intention is the correct approach (trying to have each ball be it's own `Thread`), you're going to quickly end up with all sorts of issues trying to do collision detection, as the state of each ball is always changing independent of each other and it won't scale well.  The array and a Swing `Timer` would be a more suitable solution.

This is the probably the closes I can get to what you want, the problem is, in order to paint it, you'd need a reference to the `Ball`, so I extended `Ball` from `JPanel` instead.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new SurfacePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Surface {
        public Dimension getSize();

        public void repaint();
    }

    public class SurfacePane extends JPanel implements Surface {
        public SurfacePane() {
            setLayout(null);
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                Ball ball = new Ball(
                        /* Random positions from 0 to windowWidth or windowHeight */
                        (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 400),
                        (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 400),
                        /* Random size from 10 to 30 */
                        (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10,
                        /* Random RGB colors*/
                        new Color(
                                (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                                (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                                (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256))
                        ),
                        /* Random velocities from -5 to 5 */
                        (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
                        (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
                        this
                );
                add(ball);
                ball.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    public class Ball extends JPanel {
        private int posX, posY, size;
        private Color color;

        private int vx = 5;
        private int vy = 5;

        private Surface surface;
        private Timer timer;

        public Ball(int posX, int posY, int size, Color color, int vx, int vy, Surface surface) {
            this.posX = posX;
            this.posY = posY;
            this.size = size;
            this.color = color;
            this.vx = vx;
            this.vy = vy;
            this.surface = surface;
            setBackground(color);
            setSize(size, size);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public void start() {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.stop();
            }
            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    update();
                    surface.repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (timer == null) {
                return;
            }
            timer.stop();
        }

        protected void update() {
            int width = surface.getSize().width;
            int height = surface.getSize().height;
            if (posX > width || posX < 0) {
                vx *= -1;
            }

            if (posY > height || posY < 0) {
                vy *= -1;
            }

            if (posX > width) {
                posX = width;
            }

            if (posX < 0) {
                posX = 0;
            }

            if (posY > height) {
                posY = height;
            }

            if (posY < 0) {
                posY = 0;
            }

            this.posX += vx;
            this.posY += vy;

            setLocation(posX, posY);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach (and even the `Thread`ed approach) is, it's not going to scale well.  For example, during my experimentation, I only got to about 5, 000 balls before I started have responsiveness issues (resizing the window lagged, alot), compared to roughly 20, 000 balls using an `ArrayList` (and a single `Timer`) - I'll be honest, the frame rate was terrible, but the UI remained relatively responsive - I could resize the window without lag

## Single `Timer`, array based example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new SurfacePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Surface {
        public Dimension getSize();

        public void repaint();
    }

    public class SurfacePane extends JPanel implements Surface {
        private List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>(32);

        public SurfacePane() {
            for (int index = 0; index < 20_000; index++) {
                Ball ball = new Ball(
                        /* Random positions from 0 to windowWidth or windowHeight */
                        (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 400),
                        (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 400),
                        /* Random size from 10 to 30 */
                        (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10,
                        /* Random RGB colors*/
                        new Color(
                                (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                                (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
                                (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 256))
                        ),
                        /* Random velocities from -5 to 5 */
                        (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
                        (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
                        this
                );
                balls.add(ball);
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (Ball ball : balls) {
                        ball.update();
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 800);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Ball ball : balls) {
                ball.paint(g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Ball {
        private int posX, posY, size;
        private Color color;

        private int vx = 5;
        private int vy = 5;

        private Surface surface;
        private Timer timer;

        public Ball(int posX, int posY, int size, Color color, int vx, int vy, Surface surface) {
            this.posX = posX;
            this.posY = posY;
            this.size = size;
            this.color = color;
            this.vx = vx;
            this.vy = vy;
            this.surface = surface;
        }

        protected void update() {
            int width = surface.getSize().width;
            int height = surface.getSize().height;
            if (posX > width || posX < 0) {
                vx *= -1;
            }

            if (posY > height || posY < 0) {
                vy *= -1;
            }

            if (posX > width) {
                posX = width;
            }

            if (posX < 0) {
                posX = 0;
            }

            if (posY > height) {
                posY = height;
            }

            if (posY < 0) {
                posY = 0;
            }

            this.posX += vx;
            this.posY += vy;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillOval(posX, posY, size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer. I appreciate it so much. And the explanation is fantastic. Unfortunately, we were specifically told to have each ball be it's own thread. But I will definitely read more on the alternative approach you gave. Again very appreciative as I am extremely new to this and just trying my best as I go.